# list field type

Tags: entities

I'm trying to add a new field to a product to the Drupal Commerce module. The field should be a select dropdown but the only field type I could find that would do that was term reference. So I googled and I found [the documentation for a list module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/list) that does exactly what I want. The sad part is I can't find the project page for this module in order to download it.

Does anyone know how I can use this module, or if there is anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this part of drupal 7 core?

Comment: lol.. thanks it is part of Core and I hadn't enabled it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal 7, the List Module described has been incorporated into core as part of the Field module. The options shown in the documentation are available when you add a field to a content type under the *Manage Fields* tab.